# whats the difference between a cascaded band pass filter and a normal band pass filter (Audio visualizer)

Tags: audio, filter, spectrum-analyzer, band-pass, lm3915

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fOj4UC.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

[image]

currently im building an audio visualizer i would like to know what is the difference between a cascaded 2nd order band pass filter and an inverting band pass filter.
which type of band pass filter is the best to be used in building an audio visualizer. 
i would like to get some feedback on what are the stages for building an audio visualizer.
based on my knowledge there should be several band pass filters to separate the frequencies based on my preference. then the signal should be rectified using a diode and a capacitor , and the output will be connected to the LEDS , in my case im using the LM3915 led driver.
i would like to get some feedback to improve my design and what would be best to build an audio visualizer.

thank you

Comment: The differences can be group delay distortion choices (depends on Q,f) and of course n-th order by sum of C's. best solution is a graphic equalizer and peak+decay detectors+ drivers (a.k.a. light organ)

Comment: It all depends how many channels and how closely-packed you want them to be spectrally.

Comment: You are not comparing apples with apples here. The first picture is a combination of two 2nd order all-pole filters (lowpass + highpass), resulting in a 4th order all-pole bandpass, while the second picture is a simple 2nd order bandpass (combination of two 1st order LP + HP).

Comment: im building 12 channels and i would like to know which of the following filters will be the best whether its the cascaded filter or the normal 2nd order band pass filter